# string comparion with the innertext of a childnode

Tags: wpf, xml

In the following code, I am trying to do a text parsing by using a streamreader. This is to get the email address from the text file. If i have no email address, combobox is left blank (index = -1). If i have a email that is found in my xml file, then i will select it. Else, i will add a node to my xml file with the new email address.

code:

```
private void Textparsing()
    {               
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Masterbuildpropertiespath))                 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                if (line.StartsWith("Builder_Email:"))
                    {   
                        string[] fields = line.Split('\t');
                        string builderemail = fields[3];
                        XmlDocument emailparse = new XmlDocument();
                        emailparse.LoadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");
                        XmlNodeList emailnode = emailparse.GetElementsByTagName("value");
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(builderemail))
                            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        else 
                            foreach (XmlNode node in emailnode)
                            {
                                if (builderemail == node.InnerText)
                                {
                                    int count = emailparse.SelectNodes("email/builderemail/builder").Count;
                                    count--;
                                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = count;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //create main node
                                    XmlNode abc = emailparse.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "builder", null);

                                    //create the first child node
                                    XmlNode value = emailparse.CreateElement("value");
                                    //set the value
                                    value.InnerText = builderemail;

                                    // add childes to father
                                    //node.AppendChild(id);
                                    abc.AppendChild(value);

                                    // find the node we want to add the new node to
                                    XmlNodeList l = emailparse.GetElementsByTagName("builderemail");
                                    // append the new node
                                    l[0].AppendChild(abc);
                                    // save the file
                                    emailparse.Save(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");

                                    //then we populate the new updated xml file into the drop down list:
                                    PopulateDDLFromXMLFile();
                                    int count = emailparse.SelectNodes("email/builderemail/builder").Count;
                                    count--;
                                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = count;
                                }
                            }

          }
```

However, I get an XmlException (Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.) at this line:

```
emailparse.LoadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");
```

Why is that so?

my xmlfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
  <builderemail>
    <builder>
      <value>abc@123.com</value>
    </builder>
    <builder>
      <value>Others</value>
    </builder>
  </builderemail>
  <manageremail>
    <manager>
      <value>abc@456.com</value>
    </manager>
    <manager>
      <value>Others</value>
    </manager>
  </manageremail>
</email>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the

```
       emailparse.Load(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");
```

method instead of

```
      emailparse.LoadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");
```

since LoadXml can load xml string, not the file.